# How to set text on parent sibling span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table and i have to edit the second column, So for when i click a cell in second column, textbox with 2 image will display.

After typing value in textbox and click editCost image, i have to set text in span. But i can't.

**Html**

```
<table class="gs">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Cost in (USD)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all"><tr class="odd">
                <td class=" sorting_1">
                    Culture 
                </td>

                <td align="right" class=" ">
                    <span></span>
                    <span> 
                        <input type="text" name="Culture" value="" id="Culture"> 
                        <img  alt="editCost">
                        <img  alt="cancelCost">
                    </span>
                </td>

            </tr><tr class="even">
                <td class=" sorting_1">
                    RedBloodCell 
                </td>

                <td align="right" class=" ">
                    <span>100</span>
                    <span> 
                        <input type="text" name="RedBloodCell" value="" id="RedBloodCell"> 
                        <img  alt="editCost">
                        <img  alt="cancelCost">
                    </span>
                </td>

            </tr><tr class="odd">
                <td class=" sorting_1">
                    WhiteBloodCell 
                </td>

                <td align="right" class=" ">
                    <span>100</span>
                    <span> 
                        <input type="text" name="WhiteBloodCell" value="" id="WhiteBloodCell"> 
                        <img  alt="editCost">
                        <img  alt="cancelCost">
                    </span>
                </td>

            </tr><tr class="odd even">
                <td class=" sorting_1">
                    WhiteBloodCell 
                </td>

                <td align="right" class=" ">
                    <span>100</span>
                    <span> 
                        <input type="text" name="WhiteBloodCell" value="" id="WhiteBloodCell"> 
                        <img  alt="editCost">
                        <img  alt="cancelCost">
                    </span>
                </td>

            </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Script**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('td span:nth-child(2)').hide();

    jQuery("table.gs tbody tr td:nth-child(2)").click(function() {
        jQuery('td span:nth-child(2)').hide();
        jQuery(this).find("span:nth-child(2)").show();
        var value = jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).text());
        jQuery(this).find("input").val(value);
        jQuery(this).find("span:nth-child(1)").text('');
    });

    jQuery('img[alt="editCost"]').click(function() {
        var value = jQuery(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val();
        jQuery(this).parent().siblings("span").text(value);
        jQuery(this).parent().hide(1);      
    });

    jQuery('img[alt="cancelCost"]').click(function() {
        var value = jQuery(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val();
        jQuery(this).parent().siblings("span").text(value);
        jQuery(this).parent().hide(1);      
    });

});
```

Comment: [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/jCHWy/16/)

Comment: Add the link to your main post, that's a bit easier. Also, what's the purpose of `.hide(1)`? Why not `.hide()`?

Comment: @BramVanroy. ya, hide() not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other solution can be something like below,

You need two changes,

1. Try to bind the click event on the span, not on the td. Since binding click on td will also get trigger when you click the edit or cancel button, although you could also add the preventDefault.
2. You had not taken the value of the input field rather you are grabbing the element.

So your code should look something like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('td span:nth-child(2)').hide();

    jQuery("table.gs tbody tr td:nth-child(2) .label").click(function() {
        jQuery('img[alt="cancelCost"]').trigger('click');
        jQuery(this).parent().find("span:nth-child(1)").hide();
        jQuery(this).parent().find("span:nth-child(2)").show();
        var value = jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).parent().text());
        jQuery(this).parent().find("input").val(value);
    });

    jQuery('img[alt="editCost"]').click(function() {
        var value = jQuery(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val();
        jQuery(this).parent().parent().find("span.label").text(value).show();
        jQuery(this).parent().hide(1);      
    });

    jQuery('img[alt="cancelCost"]').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).parent().hide(1);      
        jQuery(this).parent().parent().find("span.label").show();
    });

});
```

Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jCHWy/32/

You are also not reverting back the value you had already before the edit. And once cancel is clicked the span is blank. Modified this also.

Comment: awesome answer, But one problem.. user should be able to edit only one cell at a time.

Comment: if i click first cell in second column, one text box is showing.. then again if i click second cell in second column again second textbox is showing.. but first textbox should be hidden when i second textbox show

Comment: Again awesome @SilverBlade.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when the click handler fires on `img[alt="editCost"]`, the event propagates and fires the click handler on `table.gs tbody tr td:nth-child(2)`, which empties the text of the span.

Add `event.stopPropagation()` to your `img[alt="editCost"]` click handler:

```
jQuery('img[alt="editCost"]').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // your code
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jCHWy/29/)

Comment: Good catch. Same goes for `cancelCost` though!

Answer (score 0):

Try `var value = jQuery(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val();`

Comment: sorry, that is copy past mistake. see i updated my question and fiddle

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
jQuery(this).closest("td").find("span").text(value);
```

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jCHWy/9/